# how to simplifying this euler expression?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

given this equation:
    $(1-2e^{-jw} + e^{-2jw})$

how does that simplify to this?
    $(1-e^{-jw})^2$

I'm not sure what algebraic steps to take to get the 2nd equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just the binomial square formula: $(a-b)^2 = a^2+b^2-2ab$, where in this case, $a=1$ and $b=e^{-jw}$. $(1-e^{-jw})^2=1^2+(e^{-jw})^2-2e^{-jw}=1+e^{-2jw}-2e^{-jw}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Substutute $u=e^{-jw}$ to obtain:
$$1-2u+u^2 \tag{1}$$
Therefore, you must obtain $(2)$ from $(1)$:
$$(1-u)^2 \tag{2}$$
Can you do this?